# Banner slider not coming at the home page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have block call in the home page and in block, I have added this content:

`{{block class="Mageplaza\BetterSlider\Block\Slider" template="Mageplaza_BetterSlider::slider.phtml" banner_id="2" }}`

But the error is coming on home page We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content.
I think I am calling the template file wrong 
any help will be appreciated

Comment: check file path of phtml file and module name also

Comment: Can you check the exact errors in reports directory under var directory?

Comment: are you using any module ?

Comment: no i am using extenstion of mageplaza